# Azure issues listing blobs

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to list out and get the blobs in my container from azure blob storage in order to be able to download the file, and send the results via my API. I've followed the instructions microsoft has here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-list?tabs=dotnet

My file structure for my blobs is {Guid}/images/{Guid}.jpg, where {Guid} is a Guid with the dashes still in place.

However, neither method actually works. I've tried both with a flat list (which won't work given that I have a hierarchical nesting) :

```
        var resultSegment = containerClient.GetBlobsAsync().AsPages();

        await foreach(var blobPage in resultSegment)
        {
            foreach(var blobItem in blobPage.Values)
            {

                using(var stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    var combinedName = Path.Combine("images/", blobItem.Name);
                    var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(combinedName);

                    await blobClient.DownloadToAsync(stream);
                    result.Add(
                    new AzureBlobResponse
                    {
                        Data = stream.ToArray(),
                        Filename = blobItem.Name
                    });
                }
            }
        }
```

merely throws a "System.FormatException" regarding the input string. I then tried modifying my code to be as so:

```
private async Task NavigateBlobHierarchy(List<AzureBlobResponse> result, string? prefix)
    {
        var resultSegment = containerClient.GetBlobsByHierarchyAsync(prefix: prefix, delimiter: "/")
            .AsPages();

        await foreach(var blobPage in resultSegment)
        {
            foreach(var blobItem in blobPage.Values)
            {
                if(blobItem.IsPrefix)
                {
                    await NavigateBlobHierarchy(result, blobItem.Prefix.Replace('/', ' ').Trim());
                } else
                {
                    using(var stream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        var combinedName = Path.Combine("images/", blobItem.Blob.Name);
                        var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(combinedName);

                        await blobClient.DownloadToAsync(stream);
                        result.Add(
                        new AzureBlobResponse
                        {
                            Data = stream.ToArray(),
                            Filename = blobItem.Blob.Name
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Where I call it like so:

```
        try
        {
            var listOfBlobs = new List<AzureBlobResponse>();
            await NavigateBlobHierarchy(listOfBlobs, "images");

            return listOfBlobs;
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw;
        }
```

This just ends up in an endless loop because it just getting hung up on the images prefix, and everything it always hits is images. What on earth am I doing wrong, this shouldn't be a complex issue to solve. I've done it before using an older API of Azure blob in a project for my old place, never had this oddity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this code .I tried it in my system able to list all files  in blobs and downloaded them locally.

```
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient("Connection string");

            // Get the container client object
            BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("test");

            // 1st method to List all blobs in the container
            foreach (BlobItem blobItem in containerClient.GetBlobs())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t" + blobItem.Name);
            }

            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("ConnectionString");
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("test");

            //2nd method to List all the files
            var blobList = container.ListBlobs(useFlatBlobListing: true);
            foreach (var blob in blobList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t" + blob.Uri);
                string name = ((CloudBlockBlob)blob).Name;
                CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(name);
                string path = (@"local path");
                string[] names = name.Split("/");
                string newPath = "";
                string fileName = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (i != (names.Length - 1))
                    {
                        path = path  +names[i]+"\\";
                        newPath = newPath + "\\" + names[i];
                    }
                    fileName = names[(names.Length - 1)];
                }
                string filePath = path  + fileName;
                if (Directory.Exists(path))
                {
                    blockBlob.DownloadToFile(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
                }
                //blockBlob.DownloadToFile(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
                else
                {
                  
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                    string filePath1 = path +fileName;
                    blockBlob.DownloadToFile(filePath1, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
                }

            }
```

OUTPUT

**Files in container (in azure blob storage)**

[image]

**Listed files**

[image]

**Locally files are saved**

[image]

**I have one folder  name  contains file called my learning inside images as shown in image**

[image]

**Same structure the file saved locally**

[image]

Comment: Ty you very much, I was able to slightly modify your code to fit my needs, odd that I had to rely on the older variant of their SDK instead of the one they have linked. Specifically, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage instead of Azure.Storage.Blob